# Is laminate flooring easier to install if compared to other flooring materials?

Tags: floor

Is laminate flooring easier to install if compared to other flooring materials?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the tools you're using/have, and your skill level with said tools.

I've installed both "click-lock" laminate, and nail down hardwood flooring. Both took about the same amount of time, and used fairly similar installation techniques.  The major difference, was that the hardwood "required" a compressor and flooring nailer/stapler.

Linoleum and other sheet products are fairly easy to install, and don't really require any special tools.

Carpet is also not that difficult, as long as you have the tools and knowledge required to stretch it.

Obviously complex room shapes complicate the installation of each product.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But it's also the lowest-quality flooring material as its wear surface consists of a picture of wood covered in clear sealer. If you're thinking about installing laminate, go for engineered hardwood or vinyl plank instead; it's the same basic easy-to-DIY system, but the wear layer is actual wood or vinyl. Both will last a lot longer than laminate.

Comment: You can pay attention to [wear ratings](http://www.builddirect.com/Laminate-Flooring/Laminate-Floors-Articles/What_is_an_AC_Rating.aspx) of laminate flooring, which will give you a much better measure of how durable it is. I installed AC-4 rated floors in my guest bedroom, and it appears to be more durable than the engineered hardwood in my living room.

Comment: @Doresoom Is this due to the durability of the flooring, or the traffic volume?  I would imagine a living room sees more traffic than a guest bedroom.

Comment: @Tester101 I actually took some of the laminate scraps and made a "doormat" out of them. I put it just inside our back door for two months in the spot our 80 lb lab/rot mix scrambles her claws every time we let her out. Not a single scratch on the laminate test section in that time frame, but the engineered wood floor in the same spot is worn through to the plywood layer. Admittedly, 2 months is a lot shorter than the 4 years it took her to accumulate that damage, but it seems to be holding up pretty well.